# Is there a keyboard shortcut for exiting or closing nuGet Package Manager Console?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I exit other windows (for example Solution Explorer) simply pushing Escape, but apparently there is no way to exit this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to leave the package manager console window.

Comment: I have edited this answer according to the comment by @wal, I will mark it as my accepted answer when it is reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this doesn't work today, but we should fix it. I just filed a bug: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/591

As a workaround, if you really want a pure keyboard shortcut, you could do Ctrl-S, W, Escape. Basically, make it go to the solution explorer, and then escape from there.  I know, many keystrokes, just a workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close PMC
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the editor (without closing PMC)